Can you prove that God is just for punishing Jesus without taking into account Jesus also being God?
If Jesus was merely a man, then God would seem unjust for punishing the innocent Jesus in place of the guilty due to violating the following:

Man is to be put to death for his own sin and not for the sin of another (Ez 18:20; Dt 24:16)

No man can ransom another or give to God the price of his life (Ps 49:7-9)


Moreover, God seems unjust for WANTING to crush the innocent man that is Jesus (Is 53:10; Lk 22:42), regardless of Jesus' willingness to follow the Father's will and lay His life down as a sacrifice. That God could desire and plan to punish/sacrifice an innocent man, His Son no less, for the sins of others would go against His character.
The only way I see God being just would be that Jesus is God. Thus, God's plan would not be the unjust sacrifice of an innocent third party but rather the just, noble sacrifice of the self. But if you can show that God is just in sacrificing Jesus even if Jesus isn't God, then please leave an answer down below.

"If Jesus was merely a man..." but Jesus is not merely a man. He is also God.

@Null I agree, but can you argue that God is just in this scenario if Jesus wasn't?

The above will need to be clarified. 1. Jesus voluntarily yielded his life. He was not killed. 2. The physical sufferings (scourging and crucifixion) were not vicarious. 3. The matter of bearing individuals' sins (before death) and the matter of bearing sin itself (the sin of the world) (through death) were matters regarding the Righteousness of God and these matters were settled privately within the Deity.  4. As it stands, the question is merging these matters and not considering the separate issues.

@another-prodigal What is the point of answering a "what if" for a situation we both agree is not true?

@Null I have conversations with my buddies who don't believe Jesus is God and was just wondering if anyone would know how to answer the question given such belief

@Nigel the issues seem separate, but they are heavily related in this situation. Answering the question involves addressing the issues altogether as you did

It's laudable to have such conversations, but it's putting the cart before the horse to try to justify the punishment Jesus suffered without agreeing Who Jesus is. It's like trying to prove the quadratic equation with someone who disagrees with you that 2 + 2 = 4 -- you've got to agree what addition means before you can use an expression which uses addition.

@Null Well the trinitarian view seems to depend on the defining of Jesus' identity in order to say the punishment was just, yet a non-"Jesus is God" view doesn't appear to have such dependency

If, as above, you accept that the issues are many (though related) then separate questions are required to answer each issue in turn. The question is glossing over the fact of many (related) issues. Questions on Stack Exchange are required to be single questions. Answering multiple questions secreted within one leads to complicated answers.

If, as per your comment above, you disagree with Trinitarian views then your question should be scoped to, and addressed to, some other viewpoint. Please see the Tour and the Help as to this feature of the site.

If you look at the answers given in the following question, you will see that before the founding of the world the Father and the Son were in AGREEMENT as to the means of dealing with sin: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103356/god-the-father-punished-the-son-as-sin-bearer-how-does-that-prove-god-s-righteo

No man can ransom another or give to God the price of his life (Ps 49:12,13)
You misinterpret this passage, forgetting verse 4:
I will incline my ear to a proverb;
    I will solve my riddle to the music of the lyre.

It is a riddle, therefore the surface meaning is incomplete. First, verse 6 speaks of a ransom of wealth and riches. No material offering, the treasure that moth and rust consume, can pay for a life. A spiritual ransom is necessary. The life of Jesus was not a material offering.
Second, when the sinner is ransomed, Jesus is not the one who pays the ransom. Jesus IS the ransom. He offers himself to the Father, saying "Father, into your hands I commit my spirit!" It is then the father who pays the ransom:
But God will ransom my soul from the power of Sheol, for he will receive me. - Psalm 49:15
God had already said that without the shedding of blood, there can be no remission of sins. He set up the riddle. It can't be a man - it must be a man.
A God of love must create a world where there is a valid ransom that can be paid. That is His justice. He designed everything so that in this universe there would be such an acceptable ransom. In Job, that man realized that he needed a human mediator who could sympathize with him (Job 9:32-25, 16:21), because God terrified him. But he also needed someone with the power of God to do the job. In my book Job Rises: Thirteen Keys to a Resilient Life, I assembled a list of eight "job requirements" (I have since found a ninth) for a savior that Job arrived at. Only someone who fulfilled all of them could save him. Since being both man and God are two of the requirements and Job was the most righteous man alive, he would know what is just and what is unjust. Therefore it is impossible that one can prove the justice of the act of paying God's ransom in the person of Jesus Christ apart from Jesus' divinity. No ransom of anything that is not both a man and God will ever suffice.
Jesus' prayer at Gethsemane completes the proof. There is not and can not be another other way. If there were (meaning that Jesus was overpaying the debt), then his loving Father would have told him.
“My Father, if this cannot pass unless I drink it, your will be done.”

Since the question was adjusted after many comments, and the 'morality' tag added, there may be a way of answering the question. If I fail, that will not be surprising, given the complexity of the question, and given that I want to cut to the bone to the basic, essential core issue here.
From a human point of view, there could be no justice in God punishing an innocent, sinless person - for anything. That would prove God to be unrighteous, and a monster in the case of punishing Jesus Christ on the cross. Further, if Jesus died vicariously - in the place of, or on behalf of - another, that could only suffice for one other person (Romans 5:7 & Psalm 49:7-9). To claim that Jesus as perfect man (and nothing more) set us an example of being "obedient to death, death on a cross" makes a mockery of what was really going on at Golgotha.
Only from the divine point of view can the fact of the Son of God adding human nature to his eternal divine nature explode with burning reality for believers who see God's righteousness demonstrated publicly at the cross. And the divine point of view is carefully opened up in God's written word to us, culminating in the person of Jesus Christ - God incarnate - walking this Earth, dying as foreordained by deity before creation began, then being raised in triumph from the grave to return to heaven. It was God in Christ, bearing the righteous wrath of God on sin so that:

"...at just the right time, when we were still powerless, Christ died
for the ungodly. Very rarely will anyone die for a righteous man,
though for a good man someone might possibly dare to die. But God
demonstrates his own love for us in this: While we were still sinners,
Christ died for us." Romans 5:6-8 NIV 1987 ed.

Notice the plural. It wasn't just for one person that Christ died, but reading the rest of that chapter, it becomes clear that we were all enemies of God when Christ willingly submitted himself to death, so that reconciliation with God could be achieved for all putting faith in Christ submitting to righteous wrath for sin:

"...be ye reconciled to God. For he hath made him to be sin for us, ho
knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him." 2
Corinthians 5:21 K.J.V.

Such a plan could only come from God, and only God in Christ could be the human conduit for God's way of reconciliation to be supremely poured out - a plan that was decided upon before creation began - see 1 Peter 1:20 & Revelation 13:8. And because the Godhead decreed this would happen, it had to happen, and it did happen because Father, Son and Holy Spirit were all involved in it coming to pass, in time, in a certain place, and in a certain person - Jesus Christ:

"He was in the world, and the world was made by him, and the world
knew him not... And the Word was made flesh, and dwelt among us...
full of grace and truth... For the law was given by Moses, but grace
and truth came by Jesus Christ. No man hath seen God at any time; the
only begotten Son, which is in the bosom of the Father, he hath
declared him." John 1:10-18 K.J.V.

That writer, the apostle John, then recorded how John the Baptist identified this man, Jesus, as "the Lamb of God which taketh away the sin of the world" and as "the Son of God" vss. 29-34.
I am not attempting to prove that it was righteous of God to punish Jesus because Jesus was God. I am simply pointing to a very few Bible texts that put the matter the other way around. Because Jesus was God incarnate, the righteousness of God punishing sin at Calvary the way it was foreordained to happen, was gloriously and publicly demonstrated - once for all time. Only those who abandon the human point of view, and humbly accept all that the Bible unwraps, as God's point of view, will ever see that. But, yes, only the fact of Jesus also being God enables that glorious revelation to be 'seen' - by faith that believes the incredible things God has revealed to us in the Bible.

Who is the person speaking in proverbs 8:22-31?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany That question on Prov.8:22-31 has already been asked on here, with many different interpretations offered by way of answers. As it goes off at a tangent to this Q here, I will not answer it, for Comments are not for going into discussions about matters the OP has not raised. I will respond no further.

Punish:

"inflict a penalty or sanction on (someone) as retribution for an offense, especially a transgression of a legal or moral code."

Retribution:

"punishment inflicted on someone as vengeance for a wrong or criminal act."

There is a significant difference between vengeful punishment and an objective penalty that is the direct consequence of one's choices.

Punishment is often a form of vengeance, where the one that inflicts the punishment enjoys the feeling of revenge (e.g. if you don't obey me, I'll torture you).
A penalty is an objective, predictable result (e.g. if you sin, you will die).

Those that strongly believe in a Hell of continual suffering get their ideas from Pagan mythology and don't seem to realize that punishment is actually mentioned only a few times in the Greek Scriptures:

Non-Christians want to inflict punishment:


Acts 4:21, 22:5, 26:11: (Priests and Pharisees want to punish Christians).
1 Peter 2:14: (Punishment by civil authorities.)


For Christians, it's better to forgive than to punish:


2 Colossians 2:6–7: "Sufficient to such a man is this punishment, which was inflicted of many.
So that contrariwise ye ought rather to forgive him, and comfort him, lest perhaps such a one should be swallowed up with overmuch sorrow."


God will "punish" those that refuse his salvation by destroying them:


Matthew 25:4: "And these shall go away into everlasting punishment: but the righteous into life eternal."
2 Thessalonians 1:8–9: "In flaming fire taking vengeance on them that know not God, and that obey not the gospel of our Lord Jesus Christ: Who shall be punished with everlasting destruction from the presence of the Lord, and from the glory of his power;"
Hebrews 10:2: "Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye, shall he be thought worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of God, and hath counted the blood of the covenant, wherewith he was sanctified, an unholy thing, and hath done despite unto the Spirit of grace?"
2 Peter 2:9: "The Lord knoweth how to deliver the godly out of temptations, and to reserve the unjust unto the day of judgment to be punished:"

In the last case, God doesn't get pleasure from destroying the wicked (1 Timothy 2:4: "Who will have all men to be saved").
Rather, they are incorrigible and there is simply no chance that they will ever accept his salvation.
Destruction is the only humane way.
This is much more a direct "penalty" than a "punishment".

Given that background, we see that God did not punish Jesus and certainly didn't take any pleasure or sense of revenge from it.
He simply allowed men to kill Jesus.
And yes, that death was unjust, but that injustice was the whole point of it.
By dying an unjust death (being without sin Jesus didn't deserve any such penalty), Jesus was able to apply that injustice to pay the (justified) penalty for others.

A fair amount of translations of Isaiah 53:10 say that God was pleased or delighted to crush Jesus. To say that God "simply allowed men to kill Jesus" doesn't take away the fact that God wanted to sacrifice Jesus, not to mention that God put Jesus in a specific point in time so that everything that happened to him would happen the way it did. If you were a judge, would you want to sacrifice your son to take the place of a murderer even if your son was willing?

@another-prodigal asks "would you want to sacrifice your son to take the place of a murderer even if your son was willing?". No, but I'm not God and can't restore life. ¶ A better question would be: Would I want my son to sell his house to pay the fine for a close friend who did something stupid and has since repented and changed his attitude and behaviour?. Perhaps not. Or perhaps yes if that person now has a loving relationship like a son to me and like a brother to my first son.

If perhaps yes, then the end justifies the means, that those who repent are forgiven at the expense of another as willed and designed in pleasure by God, yet we both know God can't do something contrary to his nature

A Just Universe Indeed, this is a just universe where Absolute Truth, Right and Wrong, Good and Evil, are manifest with Justice prevailing because of an Providential Almighty God.
And as pointed out, each man is responsible for his actions, his own actions, and will be held accountable by a just God when he stands before the Bar on Judgment/Reward Day. (Matthew 25:31-46)
Equally Great Attribute But along with justice, holiness, and righteousness as Divine attributes, God is also a loving God. His charity, coupled with mercy and grace, is an effulgent, effervescent part of His glory!
And it is His love that brought Himself to the earth to redeem fallen mankind! For God so love the world... is the oft repeated verse from the Bible (John 3:16). In the mystery of Incarnation, God placed Himself on the altar of redeeming sacrifice as an act of unselfish love.

When we were yet without strength, in due time Christ died for the ungodly. For scarcely for a righteous man will one die; yet perhaps for a good man some would even dare to die.But God commended His love toward us, in that while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us. (Romans 5:6-8)


Who shall separate us from the love of Christ? Shall tribulation, or distress, or persecution, or famine, or nakedness, or peril, or sword?...No, in all these things we are more than conquerors through Him who loved us!...nothing shall separate us from the love of God, which is in Christ Jesus our Lord. (Romans 8:35, 37, 39)

Jesus could have called ten thousand angels to deliver Him from the cross of crucifixion. But He had been convicted of love in the first degree, and it was love, not nails, that restrained Jesus on the cross.
Innocence was crucified, not just an innocent man. That would have been unjust. The Just died for the unjust. But truth crushed to earth will rise again! And Jesus did rise again...now surrounded with the joy of a company of redeemed people by His side.  People He loved enough to redeem with His own blood!
Love Abounding Is it out of the question that Someone, even God, should send His Son to die for others? Does that speak against a father who would do such a thing?
Just recall that thousands of fathers sent their sons overseas to fight and die in a foreign land for the benefit of people they had never met or known! (WW II) But our Heavenly Father knows us---he knows our failures and shortcomings---and sent His Son anyway. Something...about...love...I reckon.

God is just because He is almighty. Might is right. Absolute might is absolute right.

The question is about God's righteousness in connection with Jesus being God. To make three short statements without showing the way Christian, biblical teaching explains how this can be so, is not an answer. Opinions have to be backed up with evidence on this site, so, can you do that, and make the connection with the deity of Christ?

"The question is about God's righteousness". "Can you prove that God is just". You dare to question God's righteousness? God's righteousness cannot be questioned, by definition; therefore, your question is invalid.

For the 6 years I've been on this site I have been stressing the righteousness and the justice of God. My question, that you say is invalid, is addressed to yourself, to encourage you to conform to the requirements of this site to give supporting evidence and not just to make 3 short statements. I hope you will check out the site requirements in the Tour.

Three short and self-evident statements.

Strongly disagree on multiple theological grounds. Perhaps you should give a denomination so we can better understand what you believe is obvious. As it is, in this format the answer seems unacceptable and useless. Also you left out a 4th and 5th self evident statement. "Power corrupts" and "Absolute Power corrupts absolutely" We expect slightly higher effort on answers and questions.

@Wyrsa, thanks for your comment. I will add some more explanation to my answer, even though I fully expect it will still be rejected. God hates denominations which are based on the doctrine of the Nicolaitans (Revelations 2:15); consequently, I belong to none. The only person with absolute power is God. Do you agree? He is not corrupt; therefore, absolute power does not corrupt. If He were corrupt, who would make the judgement? A judgement without punishment is vanity.

@Geoffrey The reason your answer would be rejected is not due to "theological differences" it is because your answer is inadequate for the guideline of the website. Your statement is perfectly valid (because it is belief and faith), but it needs elaboration. At the very minimum cite the Bible verses that led you to your answer.  Can you elaborate please on what you mean by the Nicolaitans? I do not believe any of the people commenting are eating sacrifices offered to idols or participating in fornication rites.
