God the Father punished the Son as sin-bearer: how does that prove God’s righteousness?
Given that in the gospel of Jesus Christ, “the righteousness of God is revealed” (Romans 1:16-17), and the gospel is the good news of what God did in Christ, how is this explained in the New Testament? It does not seem obvious at first sight. Yet in Romans 3:21 to 26 we are told this declares God’s righteousness.
Could those who believe God’s righteousness was demonstrated at Golgotha please answer?
What key point(s) link God’s righteousness with the punishment of God's wrath poured out?
EDIT: To clarify, Isaiah said Messiah would be punished by God in chapter 53: "...we considered him stricken by God, smitten by him, and afflicted... the punishment that brought us peace was upon him... Yet it pleased the Lord to bruise him; he hath put him to grief." Consider the basic premise of this Q to be Isaiah 53:4-5 & 10.

Who teaches that yhwh punished his son?

@Kristopher  The prophet Isaiah foretold  amazing details of that punishment in chapter 53: "we considered him stricken by God, smitten by him, and afflicted... the punishment that brought us peace was upon him." And no, it cannot be migrated to Hermeneutics as it does not ask for analysis of one particular text.

The punishment was allowed by God for the good of fallen mankind.  But the punishment was brought by the enemy of God. https://www.calebwoodbridge.com/blog/did-god-punish-jesus-2/

@Kristopher The punishment was not only allowed by God, Christ was "delivered" by Him to fulfill God's plan for humanity:  Acts 2:23 "Him, being delivered by the determinate counsel and foreknowledge of God, ye have taken, and by wicked hands have crucified and slain:"  1 Cor 2:8 "Which none of the princes of this world knew: for had they known it, they would not have crucified the Lord of glory."

Anne, is this not just a misconception? People think of sin as a legal type of thing. You are guilty or innocent. When it is more like... You are God's friend or you aren't. Then you pile on top of that the misunderstanding of how deeply the Passion of Christ fulfilled the law...

@Wyrsa  We are spiritually alive to God, or we are spiritually dead. Until what God did in Christ deals with sin, we cannot do anything to become God's friend. Abraham was, due to his faith; before he was circumcised, before he obeyed. Nothing has changed. It is the faith of Christ that saves us from the condemnation of sin (Gal.2:20 KJ). It was not Christ 'fulfilling the law' that saved, but him bearing the punishment for sin we all deserve, in our stead. So God's righteous punishment for sin was borne by Christ though he was sinless. It wasn't his Passion. It was his faith unto death.

Anne, do you believe Christ and God are seperate in some way?  Because you just said a sentence that implies a separation. "God's righteous punishment for sin was borne by Christ (God) though He was sinless. It wasn't His (God's) Passion. It was His (God's) faith unto death" So... it was God's Faith in God? I'm now very very confused about what you are trying to say.

When the Son became flesh, he left heaven to walk on Earth. That is why I stuck to saying 'Christ' those 3 times whereas you added (God) each time. I know that the Word, who became flesh, is God, but he is not the Father, nor is he the Holy Spirit. That distinction (not 'separation') must be carefully maintained. I strive to do that, So when I referred to Gal. 2:20 KJ, it says of Christians that, in the flesh, they "now live by the faith of the Son of God..." Our faith is in the Son of God who lived by faith, to death on a cross. And was raised.

To answer the question I looked in John Metcalfe's book 'Justification by Faith', provided by The John Metcalfe Publishing Trust.
I eventually found the below at my own bookmark. It was the next portion I was to read.
John Metcalfe does not fill his text with scripture reference details. I am glad he does not for his content is so full of scripture that it would detract from his argument to fill the page with chapter/verse details.
I find that reading his books is very close to reading scripture itself.
Italics and bold emphasis are my own.

By faith Jesus was laid upon the altar of God, the commandments written upon tables of stone, testifying against the Surety, as the fire was kindled below, and the curse sounded above. Vengeance rose up from beneath, and out of the throne proceeded lightnings, thunders and voices.
The curse sounded loud and long from heaven and, again and again, the great 'Amen' sounded and echoed over the lonely Sufferer who absorbed every curse, every sanction, every recompense of reward, until none remained.
Christ in his death met all the legal penalties for his people, at once discharging the transgressors from all debt for ever, and the Judge from all vengeance world without end.
He blotted out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to the cross. The ashes of cancelled transgressions fell away as dust through the grating of the altar of judgment, drifting pale into the great void to be remembered no more.
By the obedience of faith, in the one great act of obedience, Jesus justified the Judge in discharging the lawless. He magnified the law and made it honourable. He delivered the transgressors under the first testament.
He brought us to God, as sons to the Father, with an inheritance of everlasting glory, world without end.
In order to meet divine righteousness he must fulfil all righteousness . . . .  he must fulfil the righteousness of God.

Justification by Faith by John Metcalfe p173

You're mistaken. God didn't punish Jesus but rather allowed Jesus to be an innocent victim of unjustified suffering.
God's Sacrifice of Atonement
Rom 3:25,26 God presented him as a sacrifice of atonement, through faith in his blood. He did this to demonstrate his justice, because in his forbearance he had left the sins committed beforehand unpunished—  he did it to demonstrate his justice at the present time, so as to be just and the one who justifies those who have faith in Jesus.
The atoning work of Christ on the cross was all about satisfying the demands of justice. The way the atonement works is that "God is just" 2Th 1:6 and what follows that verse indicates that there are two arms of justice. One punishes the wicked and the other compensates victims of unjustified suffering. Jesus, dying as a victim of unjustified suffering, was awarded compensation with which he used to pay off the debt of others regarding their sin, one arm of justice canceling out the other, so that the grace of forgiveness may be applied, justice having been satisfied.
Jesus was uniquely qualified to do so. For it is written, “No man can redeem the life of another or give to God a ransom for him— the ransom for a life is costly” Ps 49:7,9 No mere mortal can atone for the sins of others. But Jesus was not a mere mortal. He is LORD and Creator. For “Through him all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made.” John 1:3 And thus the value of his unjustified suffering was so much more than that of a mere mortal that it could pay for the sins of the world.
"In him we have redemption through his blood, the forgiveness of sins, in accordance with the riches of God’s grace" Eph 1:7 And with regards to the extent of his atonement, "He is the atoning sacrifice for our sins, and not only for ours but also for the sins of the whole world." 1John 2:2 But to be qualified to be saved one must put faith in Christ, one essential element of which is putting faith in his atoning work on the cross as being sufficient for the payment for one's sins.

Christ was not a "victim", He freely gave His life.  Philippians 2:8 "And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross."  He could have annihilated them all that day with the uttering of a single word, but rather stuck with the foreordained plan of salvation for humanity...thus willingly receiving the punishment that WE deserved on our behalf.  He is the savior of humanity from eternal spiritual death..."specially those who will believe" (1 Tim 4:10).

My Q was initially flawed, and I have now amended it to get the focus back on the righteousness of God.

Where in Scripture does it say that Jesus received compensation that he then used to pay our debt? It was his precious blood poured out for us that payed our debt. Being God his blood was so precious that it was sufficient to pay each of our debts, each one being infinite in its magnitude (see 1 Peter 1:17-19).


Christ was without sin, yet was punished

Why do you say he was punished?
God created rules that define how the universe operates.
E.g. the law of gravity says that things fall down.
Similarly there is a law that says that souls that sin will die.
Both laws define a cause and effect relationship; they have nothing to do with punishment.
Suppose I tell my son not to climb the tree in our backyard.
If he later does climb it and falls down and breaks his arm, do you think that injury was his punishment for disobeying me?
Do you think I would even want to punish him for it?
I would forgive him, not punish him, just as God does with human sin.
But unlike with God's love through Jesus's sacrifice, my son's arm would still be broken.
The basic premise of this question is flawed.
God wants to save people from the consequences of their actions, not to punish them.

Romans 6:23 "For the wages of sin is death; but the gift of God is eternal life through Jesus Christ our Lord."  The "wage" is the 'punishment'.  The death of Christ is our 'death'.  The sin He left in the ground was our sin.  His resurrection is our new spiritual life upon having faith in this (1 Cor 15:1-4).

@MarkVestal. "the wages of sin is death (the natural consequence of one's actions, not punishment). "the gift of God is eternal life" (not something one can earn or deserve).¶ Are you disagreeing with my statement, "God wants to save people from the consequences of their actions, not to punish them.", and claiming that God wants to punish people?

Isaiah said Messiah would be punished by God in chapter 53: "...we considered him stricken by God, smitten by him, and afflicted... the punishment that brought us peace was upon him." Consider the basic premise of this Q to be Isaiah 53:4-5 & 10.

Ray, to the contrary.  God loves humanity so much that He gave us Christ, who assumed the death (punishment) that we as humans in our sin nature deserve. We are incapable of being in God's presence in our current state. Only upon being 'in Christ' through faith in Him are we then "made the righteousness of God" for His acceptance. We are all born spiritually dead, but all already have forgiveness through Christ's shed blood. What we need prior to our physical death is new spiritual life (not forgiveness). Yes, salvation from a spiritual death comes upon having faith alone in Christ alone.

"the punishment that brought us peace was upon him" — The Hebrew word there translated as "punishment" is H4148 - mûsār, meaning "discipline, chastening, correction", not "punishment". ¶ The problem with this question isn't the question itself, but its use of the word "punish". Of the four current questions, two point out that God didn't punish Jesus, and the other two never use the "punish" word.

@MarkVestal, I'm not disagreeing with what you said, or with the original question. I'm disagreeing with the concept that God punished Jesus.

I understand.  Maybe It is better to say that God punished the sin that Christ was made to be for us...rather than punishing Christ just for being Christ, although it was indeed Jesus Christ who made the atoning sacrifice for us.  I certainly don't want to take anything away from the price that He alone paid on our behalf though.

I agree with Ray on this one the question is a little flawed. However it is seeking answers. I think it should be remembered from Olt Testament Sanctuary, Christs atonement only applies to CONFESSED sin. Those who did not confess their sins were not forgiven.

@adam Paul never states that it is only confessed sins that Christ forgave. We have faith in Christ's blood for the forgiveness of all of our sins, as we play no part in the forgiveness that His blood alone purchased. I believe you may be confusing what biblical Israel must do for their sins to be "blotted out" when Christ returns, with what Christ crucified means for the church, the body of Christ.  Rom 3:25 "Whom God hath set forth to be a propitiation through faith in his blood, to declare his righteousness for the remission of sins that are past, through the forbearance of God;"

@adam  Yes, my Q was initially flawed, and I have now amended it to get the focus back on the righteousness of God. Thank you for pointing out the matter of sin confessed (which must lead to repentance of our sin) as this relates directly to God's righteous judgment.

@Anne Just to clarify, God's righteous judgement of our sins occurred on the cross.  Believers are not judged by their sins ("all things are lawful" now).  Believers are judged by their post-salvation works for God and rewarded accordingly at the judgement seat of Christ...not at the White Throne for unbelievers.

@ Mark Vestal ... we dont get the idea that only confessed sin is forgiven from the apostle Paul. It comes from the Old Testament Sanctuary Services themselves. How is it you think only New Testament sources explain Old Testament doctrine? Atonement cannot be made for unconfessed sin...thats because it's a free gift that must be accepted by the recipient. That requires confession obviously as you cant gift something useful if the recipient doesnt accept it. You should already know this.

@adam The gift of forgiveness does not require our confession.  Christ purchased forgiveness with His blood, but you do not have to believe this for it to have happened.  For instance, I forgive you for your last comment that I "should already know this", but I do not require you to believe that I have forgiven you for my forgiveness to have occurred. Forgiveness of our sins occurred at the cross whether we believe that it did or not.  Salvation occurs at the moment of believing that forgiveness DID occur that day, therefore nothing of us (Eph 2:8-9) is required for God's grace to be gifted.

@MarkVestal says "nothing of us is required for God's grace to be gifted" — What about Acts 2:38: "Repent, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins"? — Repentance is a change to one's character and behaviour, and that requires an acknowledgement (even if only to oneself) of what needs to change.

@RayButterworth Who is Peter speaking to in Acts chapter 2?

@MarkVestal, "Jews, devout men, out of every nation under heaven" — How is that relevant?

@RayButterworth Yes! Acts 2:22 "Ye men of Israel, hear these words; Jesus of Nazareth, a man approved of God among you by miracles and wonders and signs, which God did by him in the midst of you, as ye yourselves also know:" None today are considered to be those men of Israel. Rom 11:11
"I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy." Rom 11:28 "As concerning the gospel, they are enemies for your sakes: but as touching the election, they are beloved for the father's sakes."

@RayButterworth As stated above, concerning OUR good news of the cross, what is stated to Israel is their bad news.  What THEY must do (confess, be baptized, endure unto the end), compared to what WE must do is antithetical.  They, because of these differences, are actually our "enemies".  We do not follow doctrine that is of our flesh, we follow Christ ascended in glory spiritually now.  2 Cor 5:16 "Wherefore henceforth know we no man after the flesh: yea, though we have known Christ after the flesh, yet now henceforth know we him no more."

Jesus came to fulfill the law (Matthew 5:17). It is thus interesting to see how the law provisioned the means for atonement.
For that, an "atonement day" was introduced by God for Israel. Today the concept is still followed by the Jewish community with Yom Kippur.

For on this day atonement shall be made for you, to purify you; from
all your sins before the Lord you shall be purified. (Leviticus 16:30)

Biblically, the ritual around it required two goats.

And he shall take of the congregation of the children of Israel two
kids of the goats for a sin offering, and one ram for a burnt
offering...
And he shall take the two goats, and present them before the LORD at
the door of the tabernacle of the congregation.
And Aaron shall cast lots upon the two goats; one lot for the LORD, and the other lot for the scapegoat [Hebrew: Azazel].
And Aaron shall bring the goat upon which the LORD’S lot fell, and
offer him for a sin offering.
But the goat, on which the lot fell to be the scapegoat, shall be
presented alive before the LORD, to make an atonement with him, and to
let him go for a scapegoat into the wilderness. (Leviticus 16:5-10)

Two goats (male kids) were obtained from the assembly of the sons of Israel by the high priest for use on the annual Day of Atonement. By the casting of lots, one goat was designated “for Jehovah,” and the other “for Azazel” (meaning "scapegoat"). After a bull had been sacrificed for the high priest and his household (doubtless including all the Levites), the goat for the LORD Jehovah was sacrificed as a sin offering. However, the scapegoat was "presented alive before the LORD, to make an atonement with him, and to let him go for a scapegoat into the wilderness.”
Atonement for this live goat issued from the blood of the goat for LORD/Jehovah, which had just been killed as a sin offering, the life of the flesh being in the blood.

For the life of the flesh is in the blood: and I have given it to you
upon the altar to make an atonement for your souls: for it is the
blood that maketh an atonement for the soul. (Leviticus 17:11)

The blood value, or life value, of the slain goat was thus transferred to the live goat - the scapegoat. Thus, though it was not killed by the priest, this scapegoat bore upon it a sin-atoning merit or a value of life. The fact that it was presented before the LORD Jehovah evidently indicates that he recognized this transfer of merit or sin-atoning power. A correspondency with this was the prescribed manner of cleansing an Israelite who was healed of leprosy, or of cleansing a house healed of that plague. In this case a living bird was dipped in the blood of a bird that had been killed. The living bird was then permitted to fly away, carrying away sin.​ Leviticus 14:1-8, 49-53.
Both goats were to be unblemished, sound, and as much alike as possible. Before the casting of lots over them, both goats stood the chance of being selected as the goat for the LORD Jehovah. After sacrificing the goat for the LORD Jehovah, the high priest laid his hands upon the head of the living goat and confessed the sins of the people over it. This goat was then sent away, being taken into the wilderness by “a ready man.” (Leviticus 16:20-22) The "scapegoat" thus symbolically carried off the people’s sins of the past year, disappearing with them into the wilderness.
The two goats were referred to as one sin offering. (Leviticus 16:5) Two were used apparently to add emphasis to what was accomplished by this provision to atone for the sins of the people. The first goat was sacrificed. The second, having the sins of the people confessed over it and being sent far away into the wilderness, added force to the forgiveness that the LORD Jehovah grants to repentant ones. Psalm 103:12 gives the assurance: “As far off as the sunrise is from the sunset, so far off from us he has put our transgressions.”
As the apostle Paul explained, by Jesus' offering of his own perfect human life as a sacrifice for the sins of mankind, he accomplished far more than had been achieved by "the blood of bulls and of goats." (Hebrews 10:4, 11, 12) He thus served as "the scapegoat", being the ‘carrier of our sicknesses,’ the one “pierced for our transgression.” (Isaiah 53:4, 5; Matthew 8:17; 1 Peter 2:24) He ‘carried away’ the sins of all who exercise faith in the value of his sacrifice. He demonstrated the provision of God to take sinfulness into complete oblivion. In these ways the goat “for Azazel” (the "scapegoat") pictures the sacrifice of Jesus Christ.
It can be seen that in his dealings with imperfect humans, God never violates his own standards of righteousness and justice. He does not declare sinful persons righteous on their own merit, thereby overlooking or condoning sin. (Psalm 143:1,2)
Thus God, through undeserved kindness, has provided a legal arrangement on the basis of Christ’s sacrifice (representing the two goats and the bull of atonement in a perfect way - as a complete "once and for all" atonement for our sins) by which He can be completely just and righteous in forgiving the sins of those exercising faith.

Very nice answer.  I would consider changing the last sentence to "...He was completely just and righteous in forgiving the sins of the world at the cross, and to offer the gift of salvation to all who will believe (1 Cor 15:1-4).  +1

The scape goat does not represent the sacrifice of Christ...you have that part completely wrong. That's the Lord's goat that was sacrificed. The reeponsibility for sin being placed on the scapegoat by the laying on of hands represents the responsibility of all sin being placed onto the devils head in the final judgement. The sanctuary service doesn't end at the cross...it ends after the second coming and judgement. That's the point of the scapegoat. -1 from me...the answer has a significant error in theology.

From jewish history it was found that the scapegoat was either attacked and killed by wild animals or thrown off a cliff. It didn't go off into a "happy ever after" fairytale story ending. Being "cast out" in biblical terms is a very bad thing...never good. For a prey animal, this means certain death when out in the wilderness and a lonely and terrifying one at that.

Biblical corroboration of your statement could be helpful. Also, I did not say that only „the scapegoat represents the sacrifice of Christ“ - you’re misrepresenting my answer. The whole ritual of atonement day foreshadowed Jesus‘ sacrifice. Jesus both paid for our sin with his blood and „bore our iniquities“ - he was „made to be sin for us“ (Isaiah 53:11; 2 Corinthians 5:21) - where do you get the idea from that the scapegoat represents the devil? Where in the Bible does it say that the Devil carries our sin and takes it away from us?

My Q was initially flawed, and I have now amended it to get the focus back on the righteousness of God.

Another passage that could strengthen this answer is Romans 8:3-4.

I'm not sure why you claim "Atonement for this live goat issued from the blood of the goat for LORD/Jehovah, which had just been killed as a sin offering".  The goat that is killed is for the people and to make atonement for the Holy place and the altar (vs. 15-20).  Never is the blood of anything applied to the scapegoat.  It is unatoned sin bearer, which why it is exiled and why the person who exiled it can't come into the camp until he cleanses himself.

@MikeBorden - Leviticus 16:21 shows that Aaron would lay both of his hands (which still had the blood from the bull and the goat on them) on the scapegoat‘s head, thus cleansing/atoning for the goat.

@JsWitness Every specific and deliberate application of blood is clearly spelled out everywhere in Leviticus except for this one instance, where the application of blood is both unmentioned and incidental?  Additionally it is also absolutely critical for the 'atonement of the scapegoat' you propose but God left that part out of His very specific and very repetitive instructions on exactly how to perform every aspect of this ceremony?  I am a bit more than skeptical for this and many other reasons.

@MikeBorden - as it is part of the entire ritual of cleansing/atoning, where does it say that the scapegoat is not part of the process? Lev 16:10 says: „ the scapegoat shall be presented alive before the LORD, to make atonement upon it, and to let it go as the scapegoat into the wilderness.“ (NKJV) - How could Aaron put atonement upon the scapegoat without using blood? Aaron‘s post-ritual cleansing is described as well in detail - he doesn’t clean his hands between the sprinkling of blood with his fingers and putting both hands on the head of the scapegoat.

Everything that got in contact with the blood during the ritual, was considered atoned for - why wouldn’t the scapegoat which got physically touched by the hands of Aaron that still got the cleansing blood on them? It‘s just a logical conclusion and in line with Leviticus 16:10, 19-21

@JsWitness if the scapegoat was cleansed, as you say, why would the individual chosen to release the scapegoat into the wilderness need to cleanse himself before coming back into the camp?

@MikeBorden The scapegoat carried the sins of all Israelites, which means the individual who brought the goat into the wilderness and released it, was himself in close contact with those sins that got carried away with/by the scapegoat. As with healed lepers whose purification was established, the now healthy individual had to wash themselves after the ritual of caring the sin away by a bird. (Leviticus 14:2,6-8) Touching a spotless living goat was normally no reason for having to clean yourself ritually. So why do you think he needed to do that?

@JsWitness Because the sin that was placed upon the scapegoat was not atoned for.  If the scapegoat had been cleansed from the sin it carried the man would have been fine.

@MikeBorden - sorry, I just had to laugh because we seem to be discussing a misunderstanding. The scapegoat was atoned for by the blood of the other goat before the sins were confessed over it. As stated in my answer „The blood value, or life value, of the slain goat was thus transferred to the live goat - the scapegoat. Thus, though it was not killed by the priest, this scapegoat bore upon it a sin-atoning merit or a value of life.“ - which is why it symbolically could carry the sins! Otherwise it would be a goat like any other ritually!

@JsWitness So to you this is the one instance in the whole book of Leviticus where it is absolutely critical for blood to be applied (from one goat to the other) but instruction to do so is completely omitted?  God is very careful to detail exactly what to do, how to do it, and when to do it except for this one time... and in this one time we have to infer that blood is applied because the priest hasn't washed his hands yet.  It's too big of a leap for me.

As stated in my answer: "A correspondency with this was the prescribed manner of cleansing an Israelite who was healed of leprosy, or of cleansing a house healed of that plague. In this case a living bird was dipped in the blood of a bird that had been killed. The living bird was then permitted to fly away, carrying away sin.​ Leviticus 14:1-8, 49-53." - I don't see why this, in principle, is not applied here with the 2 goats, as the meaning/purpose behind this ritual is more or less the same, only in greater scale with the Day of Atonement.

@JsWitness The procedure with the birds was prescribed in great detail.  That is the difference and it is a big difference.  The care with which God instructed Moses is intended to leave nothing out and disallow adding anything in.  If God wanted blood applied to the scapegoat He would have instructed it to be done.

I would object that if God wanted to NOT have blood on the scapegoat, he would have instructed the High Priest to first wash their hands before touching the scapegoat. He hardly could have dipped the scapegoat in the other goat's blood (as was done with the bird). Sprinkling the blood on the scapegoat was not necessary as he would touch the scapegoat‘s head with both hands, and as one of them had the killed goat‘s blood on it, some of the blood must have landed on the head of the scapegoat. While I agree that this is not explicitly said in the text, logic would imply it.

It is all about God's love for humanity.
Romans 8:34-39

Who is he that condemneth? It is Christ that died, yea rather, that is risen again, who is even at the right hand of God, who also maketh intercession for us.
35 Who shall separate us from the love of Christ? shall tribulation, or distress, or persecution, or famine, or nakedness, or peril, or sword?
36 As it is written, For thy sake we are killed all the day long; we are accounted as sheep for the slaughter.
37 Nay, in all these things we are more than conquerors through him that loved us.
38 For I am persuaded, that neither death, nor life, nor angels, nor principalities, nor powers, nor things present, nor things to come,
39 Nor height, nor depth, nor any other creature, shall be able to separate us from the love of God, which is in Christ Jesus our Lord.

Imagine this world if everything that everyone did was out of their love for their neighbor/humanity.  Righteousness indeed!
2 Corinthians 5:21

For he hath made him to be sin for us, who knew no sin; that we might be made the righteousness of God in him.


My Q was initially flawed, and I have now amended it to get the focus back on the righteousness of God.

@Anne Thanks! My point was that if we consider God's righteous actions as coming from His love (although we may not see how while living), we can more easily submit to His righteousness. The question made me consider something.  When I think of Christ being crucified I am always saddened by it (as I suspect most are), but when you consider the important  fact that "He who knew no sin was made to be sin for us", and view Him on the cross as being that, our sins, rather than as God in human form, it brings on a different outlook regarding the punishment that He is receiving on our behalf. cont..

@Anne At some point in the life of a sinner they will hopefully begin to hate their sin/sin nature. They begin wanting it out of their life. They hate it but they can't escape it being trapped in this flesh (consider what Paul says in Romans 7). How do they conquer it?  Look to the cross! Slay the sin that Christ defeated by recognizing His victory over it for us! Every wound, every whip, every punishment that He suffered was for the sin that I could not defeat, but He defeated it FOR ME all because of His love!  THAT is THE display of God's righteousness!  Thank you so much for the question!

So many answers here focus on some legal interpretation or laser in on a word. It is truly insufficient to zero in on such small details compared to the true consequences of the Passion of Christ.
I'm eastern orthodox (EO henceforth), and I propose that we consider some fundamental points and then address the question. It is likely that specific points will deviate towards the subject of salvation, because that is what Theology is about, and you are asking about a key part of it.
There is a short answer at the bottom. :)

Sin is not a legal type of thing.
Instead of sin being a "legal stain" on our soul, sin is a state of being separated from God. We still however commit sinful actions. That is to say, we still commit actions that separate us from God.
It is really easy to think of sin as a legal thing, even scripture refers to "The Law".

Righteousness in what sense? (As it applies to Humans)
The EO church fathers do not understand the term "righteousness" in a forensic sense. That is we do not believe that God "declares/counts" us as righteous or "imputes" righteousness to us while we remain in a state of sinfulness.
The forensic interpretation would make our salvation simply a legalistic fiction, God treats us as if we were righteous even though we are not.
There is also this old concept of "merit" vs "sin", a righteousness by works type of thought. This is also not correct (despite the Council of Trent, 1547). This thought is scattered throughout the christian world (even within the EO). This is salvation by works though, and ultimately the same as suggesting anubis weighs our hearts...
These interpretations (and many others) ultimately fail to appreciate the fullness of God's Grace, both in enabling us to perform good works and in forgiving us fully when we sincerely repent.

Righteousness of God, as we understand it.

Greek patristic tradition generally interprets the Pauline notion of dikaiosyne as “righteousness,” rather than as “justice” in the forensic sense. That is, the term refers first to God’s own quality of righteousness, understood more as an expression of love and mercy than as one of divine justice that must be “satisfied.”


The Sacrifice of Christ was a fulfillment of the Law
See my answer here please: Answer to a different question about sacrifices

"...the sacrificial system has been fulfilled..." and "... Christ makes all future sacrifices unnecessary..."

So yes, Christ did bare our sins... but if you read through my answer you'll see this.

There is only one instance in the entire sacrificial system in which sins are placed upon an animal, on the scapegoat on the Day of Atonement, and that animal is expressly not sacrificed, because bearing the sins of the people it is unclean. The imagery of the scapegoat is certainly applied to Christ in the New Testament, in both Hebrews and the synoptic Gospels, as well as in early Christian writings like the Epistle of Barnabas. But this imagery of Christ as sin bearer is not, strictly speaking, sacrificial imagery. (Fr. Stephen De Young, "The Sacrifice to end all sacrifices)

During the sermon on the mount, (Matthew 5:14-19) The Lord explains the relationship between his teaching the Law of the Old Testament. Christ wishes to fulfill the law. He is not to abolish the Law, but to fulfill it.
During the life of Christ (including the Passion) the old Law was perfected.

So how does Golgotha show the righteousness of God?

In the Eastern perspective, there is no thought that we must accumulate merits in order to justify ourselves before God, although our faithful often seem (as evidenced in Confession) to feel that if we are to be saved, our good works must outweigh our sins. Nor, on the other hand, is there a denial of the place and importance of good works in Christian life (Ephesians 2:8-10!). Salvation is accomplished by grace in response to faith. But that faith cannot be passive; it must express itself, not merely by confessing Jesus as “personal Lord and Savior,” but by feeding, clothing, visiting and otherwise caring for the “least” of Jesus’ brethren (Mt 25).
What we are saved from is the key issue here. Rather than view salvation primarily as a forensic liberation from guilt through imputed or imparted righteousness, we should see it as incorporation, by baptism, into Christ’s death and resurrection, such that we “die and rise” with Him. Thus we are saved from Death. We are freed from this ultimate consequence of sin and guilt—but only as a divinely bestowed gift of God’s ineffable love, expressed in the suffering death of His Son, a gift to which we respond with faith that issues in love. That response, through the action of the indwelling Spirit, enables us finally to share in Christ’s own resurrection and glorification, attaining what the Greek Fathers call theôsis or “deification” (which means existential participation in God’s life, and not ontological confusion between God and His human creatures)
(Quote from the Orthodox Church of America written by Fr. John Breck)

Golgotha shows the righteousness of God, because it is the moment in time that allows us all to be saved. This is the moment in time we participate in at each Divine Liturgy. (But that is another topic entirely)

But what about Isaiah 53:4-5,10??

But He was wounded for our transgressions, He was bruised for our iniquities, the chastisement of peace was upon Him, by His stripes we are healed. All we, like sheep, have gone astray; every man has wandered in his own way. And He delivered Him for our sins; and He opened not His mouth for all His affliction. He was brought as a sheep to the slaughter, and as a lamb before his shearer is dumb, so He openeth not His mouth. In His humiliation, His judgment was taken away.”[Isaiah 53:1-8] Accordingly, after He was crucified, even all His acquaintances forsook Him, having denied Him; and afterwards, when He had risen from the dead and appeared to them, and had taught them to read the prophecies in which all these things were foretold ... (Justin Martyr, Ante-Nicene Fathers, Volume 1, page 179)


... also, He who rules, and who feeds the people of His Father, has come. Those, again, who declare that at His coming “the lame man shall leap as an hart, and the tongue of the dumb shall [speak] plainly, and the eyes of the blind shall be opened, and the ears of the deaf shall hear,” and that “the hands which hang down, and the feeble knees, shall be strengthened,” and that “the dead which are in the grave shall arise,” and that He Himself “shall take [upon Him] our weaknesses, and bear our sorrows,”[Isaiah 53:4] — [all these] proclaimed those works of healing which were accomplished by Him (Irenæus, Ante-Nicene Fathers, Volume 1, page 510)


... as being Himself Life, He said this: “I lay it down of myself.” And He who gives life bountifully to all, has His side pierced with a spear. And He who raises the dead is wrapped in linen and laid in a sepulchre, and on the third day He is raised again by the Father, though Himself the Resurrection and the Life. For all these things has He finished for us, who for our sakes was made as we are. For “Himself hath borne our infirmities, and carried our diseases; and for our sakes He was afflicted,”[Isaiah 53:4] as Isaiah the prophet has said. This is He who was hymned by the angels, and seen by the shepherds, and waited for by Simeon, and witnessed to by Anna. This is He who was inquired after by the wise men, and indicated by the star; He who was engaged ... (Hippolytus, Ante-Nicene Fathers, Volume 5, page 230)


... yourselves have given your soul on account of your sins, ye should see a seed of a long life. And the Lord is pleased to rescue His soul from pains, to show Him light, and to form it through His understanding; to justify the Just One, who serves many well; and He shall Himself bear their sins. Therefore He shall inherit many, and He shall divide the spoils of the mighty; and He was numbered amongst the transgressors; and Himself bare the sins of many, and He was delivered for their iniquities.”[Isaiah 53:3-12] Consider also that passage of this same prophet which Christ actually declared to be fulfilled in Himself, when He recited it in the synagogue, in discharging the function of the reader: “The Spirit of the Lord is upon me, because He hath anointed ... (Augustine, Nicene and Post-Nicene Fathers, Series 1, Volume 5, page 36)


The Church teaches that Christ's Resurrection guarantees our salvation and that together with His Ascension it brings to fruition God's union with us for all eternity. While the Resurrection has not yet abolished the reality of death, it has revealed its powerlessness over us in Christ. (Based Hebrews 2:14-15)
The Church also teaches that mankind shares in Christ's Resurrection, and that all mankind will rise from the dead.

"Christ is risen from the dead, trampling down death by death, and upon those in the tombs bestowing life." -Resurrectional Apolytikion.


Short version: It shows God's love and mercy, which is part of His Righteousness. Jesus willingly was sacrificed, to fulfill/perfect the entirety of the law, because of that moment we are saved.

That's a comprehensive answer with many points of agreement. But it is the Law of God that demands perfect justice be meted out to sinners, those who offend against God, even in their thoughts and lustful desires as Jesus showed. His Law condemns all of us; nobody can keep God's Law perfectly. The Law does not offer mercy, "for the law is not of faith" Gal.3:12. "The law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ" Jn.1:17. "For Christ is the END of the law for righteousness to every one that believes... But the righteousness which is of faith is the word of faith which we

preach; that if thou shalt confess with thy mouth the Lord Jesus, and shalt believe in thine heart that God hath raised him from the dead, thou shalt be saved. For with the heart man believeth unto righteousness; and with the mouth confession is made unto salvation... Faith comes by hearing the word of God." Rom. 10:4-17 We are not saved at the moment of Christ's sacrifice/resurrection. Faith in that has to be expressed, and saving faith is a gift from God! Eph. 2:8-9 (not of works).

@Anne I try to give comprehensive answers that are aligned with accepted church teachings and scripture as understood by the Orthodox Church, as well as all of the saints and people who are wiser than I am about these issues. "Do not slight the discourse of the sages, but turn to their maxims, because from them you will learn discipline and how to serve the great." (Wisdom of Sirach 8:8)

@Anne, I respect your choice and faith, but this is how my church understands the issue you raised. We have fundamental differences, but we must both surely agree... without Christ's Sacrifice everything else would not be. It is the fundamental most core element of salvation, without Christ there is no life (John 14:6)

Yes, we are surely agreed on the fundamental, core element of salvation of Christ's sacrifice, despite differences in other matters.  Shalom.

The gospel of Christ reveals how a holy God can forgive sins in righteousness.  The gospel of Christ faces the real issue, the nature of God, who is also the lawgiver and the Judge.  How could a holy and righteous God allow sin to go unpunished?
We are all condemned by the law and deserving of punishment, yet, by the faith of the Son of God, justice was met and God’s righteousness revealed (Romans 1:16-17).
This forgiveness of sins is given “unto all and upon all them that believe”.  Our redemption is in Christ Jesus whom God sent forth (Romans 3:22-26).
The Son of God willingly took our place, and on our behalf submitted passively, by faith, to God’s just judgment against sin.  The faith of Jesus Christ was honoured, God’s justice was met, and His righteousness was revealed to all who believe.
The righteous condemnation and judgment, the wrath of God upon sinners, was transferred upon His Son as agreed upon by Father and Son before the founding of the world.  In this manner, justice was satisfied revealing the righteousness of God to every person who ever has, or ever will, believe in Jesus Christ who, in his body, on the cross, bore the sin of the world.
The servant king bore the sins of other people – he himself was innocent of any sin.  In the death of Christ mercy and justice met, with mercy rejoicing in the righteousness of a holy and just God.
[Extracts paraphrased from the publication Justification by Faith by John Metcalfe]

Righteousness is defined simply as justice. δῐκαι-οσύνη , ἡ , righteousness, justice. Thayer:


in the broad sense, the state of him who is such as he ought to be, righteousness (German Rechtbeschaffenheit); the condition acceptable to God (German Gottwohlgefalligkeit);

in a closer sense, justice, or the virtue which gives each one his due; it is said to belong to God and Christ, as bestowing ἰσότιμον πίστιν upon all Christians impartially, 2Pe 1:1; of judicial justice, Rom 9:28



In Romans 3 context, the new criteria and manner of divine justice has been described that now, his requirement of virtue appeared through Christian faith apart from the Moses law works. It is God's gracious new way of righteousness without the law covenant, as Christ has been offered as a sacrifice for redemption and forgiveness of former sins. The emphasis is on the new way of justice that is gracious, rather than God's justice itself.
The concept of the sacrificial death atoning for sins is a common concept in the Hebrew Bible, thus, it was not considered shocking and innovative view to the believers. Biblestudying cites Rabbinic sources:

The death of a righteous man atones for the sins of many. It is only the blood (of the righteous) that provides atonement for sins even as the death of the High Priest atones for sin.
56 Here are the words of a respected Orthodox Jewish historian, Rabbi Berel Wein. How was it that the Jewish people survived the horrors of the massacres in Eastern Europe in the seventeenth century? According to Rabbi Wein:
Another consideration tinged the Jewish response to the slaughter of its people. It was an old Jewish tradition dating back to Biblical times that the death of the righteous and innocent served as an expiation for the sins of the nation or the world. The stories of Isaac and of Nadav and Avihu, the prophetic description of Israel as the long-suffering servant of the Lord, the sacrificial service in the Temple – all served to reinforce this basic concept of the death of the righteous as an atonement for the sins of other men. Jews nurtured this classic idea of death as an atonement, and this attitude towards their own tragedies was their constant companion throughout their turbulent exile. Therefore, the wholly bleak picture of unreasoning slaughter was somewhat relieved by the fact that the innocent did not die in vain and that the betterment of Israel and humankind somehow was advanced by their “stretching their neck to be slaughtered.” What is amazing is that this abstract, sophisticated, theological thought should have become so ingrained in the psyche of the people that even the least educated and most simplistic of Jews understood the lesson and acted upon it, giving up precious life in a soaring act of belief and affirmation of the better tomorrow. This spirit of the Jews is truly reflected in the historical chronicle of the time: “Would the Holy One, Blessed is He, dispense judgment without justice? But we may say that he whom God loves will be chastised. For since the day the Holy Temple was destroyed, the righteous are seized by death for the iniquities of the generation” (Yeven Metzulah, end of Chapter 15). 262 – Brown, Answering Jewish Objections to Jesus, Volume 2, Theological Objections, p. 155
Footnote 262: Berel Wein, The Triumph of Survival: The Story of the Jews in the Modern Era 1650-1990 (Brooklyn, N.Y.: Shaar, 1990), 14.

In similar fashion, the Zohar, the most sacred book of Jewish mysticism, states, “As long as Israel dwelt in the Holy Land, the rituals and the sacrifices they performed [in the Temple] removed all those diseases from the world; now the Messiah removes them from the children of the world (2:212a).” 263


